# Error(12,5): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "LC_SQLERRM" when expecting one of the following: language

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE APPS.XX_PROC_ADI_test  AS

  PROCEDURE XX_INS_DATA_ADI (
p_primary_uom_flag        VARCHAR2,
    p_list_line_type_code     VARCHAR2,
    p_price_break_type_code   VARCHAR2,
    p_arithmetic_operator     VARCHAR2,
    p_operand                 NUMBER,
      p_start_date_active       DATE,
    p_end_date_active         DATE,
    p_product_precedence      NUMBER
);    
END;

 SET VERIFY OFF
  WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT FAILURE ROLLBACK;
  CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE APPS.XX_PROC_ADI_test  AS

  PROCEDURE XX_INS_DATA_ADI (
    p_primary_uom_flag        VARCHAR2,
    p_list_line_type_code     VARCHAR2,
    p_price_break_type_code   VARCHAR2,
    p_arithmetic_operator     VARCHAR2,
    p_operand                 NUMBER,
      p_start_date_active       DATE,
    p_end_date_active         DATE,
    p_product_precedence      NUMBER
    )IS
    lc_sqlerrm              VARCHAR2(2000);
      lc_error_msg            VARCHAR2 (2000);
     
      l_responsibility_id     NUMBER := apps.fnd_global.resp_id;
      l_resp_application_id   NUMBER := apps.fnd_global.resp_appl_id;
      l_org_id                NUMBER := apps.fnd_global.org_id;
      l_user_id               NUMBER := apps.fnd_global.user_id;
     
     
    BEGIN
     INSERT INTO QP_LIST_LINES(
      primary_uom_flag,
        list_line_type_code,
        price_break_type_code,
        arithmetic_operator,
        operand,
        start_date_active,
        end_date_active,
        product_precedence
        )
         VALUES (
         p_primary_uom_flag,
            p_list_line_type_code,
            p_price_break_type_code,
            p_arithmetic_operator,
            p_operand,
            p_start_date_active,
            p_end_date_active,
            p_product_precedence
     );

    COMMIT;
    EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
    lc_sqlerrm := SUBSTR(SQLERRM,1,1999);

    raise_application_error (-20001, 'OTHER_EXCEPTION - MSG | ' || lc_sqlerrm);
  END; 
  END XX_INS_DATA_ADI;
END;
```

Comment: Just to comment on the code (once you've got it working following Littlefoot's answer): normally an `lc_` prefix indicates a local constant, not a variable as you have above. But you don't need to store sqlerrm in a variable anyway. `raise_application_error([code], [message], true);` will include the error stack, so don't concatenate it into the message. Instead, use the message to provide some useful details about what went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to use this (and your tool supports it), use it at the beginning:

```
SET VERIFY OFF
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT FAILURE ROLLBACK;
```

Then create

- package **specification** first
- package **body** next

---

```
create or replace package xx_proc_adi_test as
  procedure xx_ins_data_adi(...);
end xx_proc_adi_test;
/

create or replace package BODY xx_proc_adi_Test as
  procedure xx_ins_data_adi(...) is
    ...
  begin
    ...
  exception
    ...
  end xx_ins_data_adi;
end xx_proc_adi_test;
/
```